# ¿Cómo guardar en base de datos en dos tablas VB.net?

Tags: vb.net, vba, webforms, aspx

Hola tengo un consulta y es la siguiente:

Quiero guardar datos en 2 tablas la primera se debe insertar en `tbSolicitudExportacion` y la otra tabla se llama `ArchivoSolExportacion` y alli se deben guardar los archivos adjuntos y obtener el id de la tabla `tbSolicitudExportacion` usando asp.vb.net

```
CREATE TABLE tbSolicitudExportacion
(
CodSolExportacion int identity(1,1)  PRIMARY KEY not null,
NumDam varchar(25),
RegNumDam varchar(25),
NBooking varchar(25),
LineaNaviera varchar(100),
NombreDespachador varchar(100),
Dni varchar(8),
descMercancia varchar(100),
NumCelular varchar(10),
Correo varchar(50),
Ruc varchar(25),
RazonSocial varchar(50)
)
```

Tabla de archivos

```
CREATE TABLE ArchivoSolExportacion
(
CodArchivoSolExp int identity(1,1) PRIMARY KEY not null,
CodSolExportacion int NOT NULL,
nombreArchivo varchar(50),
archivo varbinary(max),
extensionArchivo varchar(10)
)
```

Mi método insertar

```
Protected Sub btnGrabar_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnGrabar.Click

        Try
            Dim numDam As String = txtNumDam.Text.Trim()
            Dim regNumDam As String = txtRegNumDam.Text.Trim()
            Dim numBooking As String = txtNumBooking.Text.Trim()
            Dim lineaNaviera As String = txtLineaNaviera.Text()
            Dim nomDespachador As String = txtNomDespachador.Text.Trim()
            Dim dni As String = txtDni.Text.Trim()
            Dim descMercancia As String = txtDescMercancia.Text.Trim()
            Dim celular As String = txtCelular.Text.Trim()
            Dim correo As String = txtCorreo.Text.Trim()
            Dim ruc As String = txtRuc.Text.Trim()
            Dim razonSocial As String = txtRazonSocial.Text.Trim()




            Dim con As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection(cadenadeConexion)
            Dim cmd As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand("sp_ins_solicitud_exportacion", con)
     'Se guarda en la primera tabla'
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@numDam", numDam)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@regNumDam", regNumDam)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@numBooking", numBooking)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lineaNaviera", lineaNaviera)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nomDespachador", nomDespachador)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dni", dni)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@descMercancia", descMercancia)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@celular", celular)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@correo", correo)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ruc", ruc)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@razonSocial", razonSocial)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@aa", AdjuntoBooking.FileBytes)

            '¿Como guardar en la segunda tabla los archivos fileupload?' 
            'Guardar en la tabla archivoSolicitud'

        AdjuntoBooking
        AdjuntoDAM
        AdjuntoGuias
        AdjuntoOpUsuales
        AdjuntoPago
        AdjuntoPagoAdic
        AdjuntoCargaFactTer
        'Campo relacionado al primer '
        CodSolExportacion

            con.Open()
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        Catch ex As Exception
            Throw ex
        End Try
    End Sub
```

Captura del formulario

Los adjuntos se deben guardar en otra tabla pero con el id relacionado de la primera tabla

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para tu caso Lo que puedes Hacer es declarar un parámetro tipo Output en tu sql, en el cual puedes regresar el valor de identity generado en tu consulta, ese parámetro lo envías  y obtienes su valor desde el código Vb,  y con ese valor puedes ejecutar tus demás inserts, para al final tener la relación.

Este es el ejemplo de como podrías hacerlo.

---

Código en Vb

```
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure

'Añade tu parámetro de Salida'
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CodSolExportacion", SqlDbType.Int)
cmd.Parameters("@CodSolExportacion").Direction = ParameterDirection.Output)

'Aquí Añades tus demás parámetros'
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@numDam", numDam)

con.Open()
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

'Después de Ejecutar tu Consulta y antes de Cerrar tu Conexión, Obtienes el valor de tu parámetro'
Dim CodSolExportacion As Integer = cmd1.Parameters("@CodSolExportacion").Value;

'Y ya con ese Id, Puedes enviarlo a tus  siguientes sp's como parámetro para insertar'
```

Ahora este seria el cambio que tienes que agregar a tu sp, para que reciba tu parámetro de salida.

---

Código en Sql

```
/*Ejemplo de el cambio  a Ejecutar en este SP*/
CREATE  PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_ins_solicitud_exportacion]
    (
      @CodSolExportacion INT OUTPUT ,
      @numDam varchar(25),
    )
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO tbSolicitudExportacion()
    VALUES()

    /*Asigno el valor  de el Insert a la variable, me regresara el Identity, que se genero en este insert*/
    SET @CodSolExportacion = SCOPE_IDENTITY();
END
```

Comment: Estimado y como recorro los archivos adjuntos para que se inserten todos a la vez después de haber obtenido el id identity en vb.net. para poder registrar a la tabla de archivoSolicitud

Comment: Puedes generar una consulta por cada archivo, o generar una función Adicional a la que le proporcionas el id, y tu archivo, y te genere el insert, de esa segunda tabla no necesitas obtener un id, únicamente asegurar que se inserto el registro,  y esa función mandarla llamar por cada archivo que quieras insertar

Comment: tendria que llamar al metodo 7 veces

Comment: si, o puedes enviar 7 parámetros a tu sp, y hacer el insert de tus 7 documentos  en esa consulta, solo si agregas un nuevo documento, tienes que enviarlo adicional y en tu sp agregar el insert

Comment: Perfecto, funciono a la perfección.